# OutOfMemoryError with TStringList

Tags: delphi, out-of-memory

i try to fill a stringlist with the use of a streamreader.
But i have an OutOfMemoryError while filling it.
i search on web but find anything about a solution.
i also try to increase capacity of my string list but it changes nothing.
Thanks for your help.

Here is my code:

```
list := TStringList.create;
//list.Capacity := 100000000; Doesn't work
Reader := TStreamReader.Create(filename, true);
try
  list.BeginUpdate;
  try
    list.Clear;
    while not Reader.EndOfStream do
    list.Add(Reader.ReadLine); // OutOfMemoryError
  finally
    list.EndUpdate;
  end;
finally
  Reader.Free;
end;
```

I forgot my xml file size is 250 mo.

Comment: Is it your *program* throwing the `EOutOfMemory` exception or is it the IDE?  Which version of Delphi?  How much memory is your application using? How much do you have?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10032215/327083

Comment: does it work with TStringList.LoadFromFile() ?

Comment: This is not at all surprising.  Loading a 250MB text file into a 32 bit process is going to be tricky. The XML file will, most likely, use an 8-bit encoding, and when you convert to native UTF-16 strings, that swells the memory load to 500MB. An we don't know what else you are trying to keep in memory. The solution is not to load it all into memory in one go.

Comment: Also, why use a `TStringList` at all?  Why not an `IXMLDocument`, etc?

Comment: Also, depending on the formatting of the XML, it may or may not have line breaks in it, which would contribute to `ReadLine()` trying to load too much at one time. And `TStringList` is horribly inefficient when loading large files/streams.  `IXMDocument` is better, but since it is DOM-based, it has to load the entire XML at one time and parse it into tree structures, which can be a lot of overhead for large XML documents.  If speed and memory usage are concerns, a SAX-based or Reader-based XML parser is best.

Comment: Why are you loading the XML in TStringList? Can you use multiple StringList to do your job?